# Notification in Android with Sound?

Tags: android

I have include the Notification with sound.
I have tried both as Default and load particular mp3 from sd card.
Now my question i include the Raw data in the Eclipse i.e. in the 
res->raw->sound.ogg
suppose i want to use this sound for my notification then how can i
use it?
Please help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create notification there is `Notification.sound` field. For filling it with raw resource use `Uri`:

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.raw.sound);
```